# applications made in turbo c++ didn't work in win 10

Tags: turbo-c++

I have downloaded turbo c++ 4.0 . It is not causing anything error. But the application I made in c++ is showing error outside of the IDE that: "this app can't run on your PC, to find a version for your PC check the software publisher". I have windows 10 64 bit, turbo c++ 4.0 x64

Thanks in advance!

Comment: don't use Turbo C++. It's much older than the first C++ standard and doesn't support modern C++ features

Comment: Thank You for this advice now i'm using VC++. And when I downloaded this i did't have a single source for a huge download package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turbo C++ creates 16bit apps.  64bit versions of Windows cannot run 16bit apps directly. 32bit versions can, though.  For 16bit apps, you can try installing DOSBox or other DOS emulator that can run 16bit code on 64bit systems.

Comment: I have installed **DOSBOX** it was provided in the package Which I downloaded install turbo c++. But please can you tell me how can I run by the DOS BOX please send an answer or an link. please!!!! please!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that we have to download **DOS-BOX** or **DOS-emulator** and navigate to the **executable file** then open it will work there on the **DOS box window** and If the program is **graphics** type then just copy the **EGAVGA.BGI** to the folder in which *exe* file is located.

**Thank you**